# Project enum display name

Tags: c#, automapper

Given the types

```
public enum Foo
{
    [Display("The bar")]
    Bar
}

public class Widget
{
    public Foo MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetDTO
{
    public string MyPropertyDisplayAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

How can I project the DTO using `Automapper` and `ProjectTo()`? Assume the extension method `GetDisplayName()` fetches the display attribute's value. This code:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.MyPropertyDisplayAttribute, 
           opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MyProperty.GetDisplayName()))
```

throws, as expected:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetDisplayName(System.Enum)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I can certainly iterate over the DTOs after they are mapped and update that property, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require an extra step.

Comment: What do you mean by "extra step"? Is `AfterMap()` not what you are looking for? The number of "steps" are somehow the same. What about a helper property of type `Foo` which uses `GetDisplayName()` to assign the string to `MyPropertyDisplayAttribute`?

Comment: I don't think `AfterMap()` works with `ProjectTo()`.  I tried it, then found this https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/415

Comment: Yes, for the same reason :) You should use `Map` instead.